# In Blender, how can I copy an animation from one bone to another using the built in python tools?

Tags: python, animation, blender, nla

I wanted to have all translation animations on a "root" bone, and all rotation animations on a child "hips" bone, but I accidentally put all the animations on the hips bone and now I cannot use root motion in the game engine!

Preferably I would not redo all the animations by hand, as I have nearly a hundred.

I tried several variations on this pseudo-code, hoping that the animation would have moved to the other bone. I keep getting errors about missing fields/methods, but it's difficult to figure out what fields I have access to in python since it's not statically typed.

```py
import bpy

# Get the root bone and the hips bone for future reference
root = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].data.bones["_rootJoint"] # Root bone with no animation called "_rootJoint"
hips = bpy.data.objects["Armature"].data.bones["CG_02"] # Hips bone that was supposed to have only rotation animations called "CG_02"

# I wish to select the actions to perform this operation on
# OR iterate through all NLA actions...???
for action in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    for point in action.fcurves.keyframe_points:
        # if this point is on the hips object:
            # for each keyframe on tracks 0, 1, and 2 (the location tracks):
                # Copy that keyframe from hips to root
                # Then remove it from hips
```

Comment: do you know that if you rename a bone with an action attached, it renames the action animation channel as well, but if the action is not connected on rename, but is connected later, then channels are bind to bones by names (not necessarily the same bones ;-))?

Answer (score 0):

I think it could be something like this (it's for 2.7x)

```
import bpy

ROOT_BONE = "_rootJoint" # Root bone with no animation called "_rootJoint"
HIPS_BONE = "CG_02" # Hips bone that was supposed to have only rotation animations called "CG_02"
    
for action in bpy.data.actions: # all actions in the file
    for fcurve in action.fcurves:
        # just rename channel, if it's a location
        _path = fcurve.data_path
        if "location" in _path:
            _new_path = _path.replace(HIPS_BONE, ROOT_BONE)
            print(f"{_path} -> {_new_path}")
            fcurve.data_path = _new_path
```